# CutyCapt seems to ignore the Xvfb screen size parameters

Tags: xvfb, html, screenshot, cutycapt

I have a problem using [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) to create images rendered for a particular screen size.

For example, if I do these:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 800x600x24" \
  ~/bin/CutyCapt/CutyCapt --url='http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=cutycapt%20xvfb' \
    --out=STACKOVERFLOW_1.png
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 800x600x24" \
  ~/bin/CutyCapt/CutyCapt --url='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65078/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-web-page-thumbnail' \
    --out=STACKOVERFLOW_2.png
```

I get images of sizes:

```
STACKOVERFLOW_1.png : 975x2611
STACKOVERFLOW_2.png : 975x2226
```

I believe any stackoverflow page will be of a width of 975 pixels. This is not what I asked (w=600).

Is it possible to create images using CutyCapt with Xvfb that are rendered for a particular screen width?

PS: `uname -a` yields `Linux yalabs-linux0.yandex.net 2.6.27-17-server #1 SMP Fri Mar 12 02:48:52 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 2):

CutyCapt is working as designed. The size of the X screen is irrelevant (unless the site's stylesheet depends on it, which is a terrible but common idea). Stack Overflow renders for a fixed width, regardless of the browser window width, so you get an image of that width.

Comment: Many thanks. I've got a confirmation from "the" source that this is a desired behavior. Alas. But thanks for your help.

Comment: @Dag That user hasn't logged in in months. It's a lost cause. He won't see your nag.

Comment: i had problems with the qt4 build of cutycapt ignoring my viewscene size. Rebuilding with qt5 solved the issue