# How to take higher resolution screenshots with CutyCapt

Tags: screenshot, xvfb, webkit, cutycapt

Assume i take a screenshot via

```
xvfb-run -s "-screen 0 1920x1080x16" cutycapt --url ... --out ...
```

then i [have learned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14228/cutycapt-seems-to-ignore-the-xvfb-screen-size-parameters) that cutycapt will not use the X sessions parameters.

How would i generate an output with cutycapt at a higher resolution, so it can be displayed nicer on e.g. 1920x1080?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/cutycapt.1.html) shows that

> --min-width
>    --min-height

can be used to adjust the output size so the resulting command would be

```
xvfb-run cutycapt --min-width=1080 --min-height=1920 --url ... --out ...
```

Note: forcing the X server to a certain resolution is not necessary, as noted in the linked question, cutycapt does its own thing.